# How to delete all sub classed entities from its super entity class by date

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a `ParentEntity` where I inherit all child entities from like so:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", indexes = {@Index(columnList = "traceId"), @Index(columnList = "idType"), @Index(columnList = "companyId"), @Index(columnList = "created")})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String idType;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    @CollectionTable(name = "unknown_fields", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL})
    @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(length = 50)
    Map<String, String> unknown = new HashMap<>();

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = new Date();
        idType = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
    }
}
```

Now I want to delete all Entities where the `created` date is lower then x. Since I have a very large number of sub classes I definitly want to avoid looping through every one of them. So I am looking for a way where I can delete from the `ParentEntity` without knowing which children might be affected.

So I have created a repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface ParentEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {

    void deleteAllInBatchByCreatedBefore(Date date);

}
```

Now while a `parentEntityRepository.deleteAllInBatch();` works as excpected the `parentEntityRepository.deleteAllInBatchByCreatedBefore(Date.valueOf(isoDate));` does not. It makes a ton of selects which takes ages until it eventually dies with an `Exception in thread "SimplePauseDetectorThread_0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. I would expect something more like `delete from ? where created at < ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I suspect this is not supported and the framework simply ignores the AllInBatch part when parsing the query method - which is why is it still works but just not as you expect.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

You can define your own query to get the expected behaviour:

```
@Transactional
public interface ParentEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {

    @Query("delete from ParentEntity p where p.created < :date) 
    void deleteAllInBatchByCreatedBefore(Date date);

}
```